# How to add commas every 3 digits character for string in Microsoft Server SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a built-in function for this task? If not, how can it be done? It is `varchar(20)`, and it only contains integers. For example, `309000 -> 309,000`.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it a varchar column or int/numeric/float? What types of data will it contain (ints only, decimals)?

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: It's `varchar(20)`, and it contains only ints. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the business tier be handling this rather than the data access layer.

Comment: @Nick: I think I have to agree with you. It actually could be done in the report using formating rules. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cascading CASE statements, which can be put into a function

```
case
when i > 999999999 then STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(i,2,0,','),6,0,','),10,0,',')
when i > 999999 then STUFF(STUFF(i,LEN(i)-5,0,','),len(i)-1,0,',')
when i > 999 then STUFF(i,LEN(i)-2,0,',')
else CONVERT(varchar(10),i)
end
```

**Note** Bear in mind the data returned is *no longer a number*, so your front-end code won't be able to use it as a number.  I would always advise for the formatting to be done *via the front-end code*.

e.g.

```
select col1, col2, col3,
    case
    when i > 999999999 then STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(i,2,0,','),6,0,','),10,0,',')
    when i > 999999 then STUFF(STUFF(i,LEN(i)-5,0,','),len(i)-1,0,',')
    when i > 999 then STUFF(i,LEN(i)-2,0,',')
    else CONVERT(varchar(10),i)
    end int_with_commas_as_varchar
from tbl
```

or create a function

```
create function dbo.formatThousands(@i int)
returns varchar(20) as
begin
return
    case
    when @i > 999999999 then STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@i,2,0,','),6,0,','),10,0,',')
    when @i > 999999 then STUFF(STUFF(@i,LEN(@i)-5,0,','),len(@i)-1,0,',')
    when @i > 999 then STUFF(@i,LEN(@i)-2,0,',')
    else CONVERT(varchar(10),@i)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
SELECT FORMAT(2123456789, '#,#')
```

Comment: That would not work without cast varchar to int... use this: `DECLARE @A varchar(20) = '2123456789'
SELECT FORMAT(Cast(@A as int), '#,#')`